# Updating deeply nested structures in clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got a structure like this:

```
[["/1417612109-first-migration.clj"  {:applied true :date-applied 1423233980}]
 ["/1417612450-second-migration.clj" {:applied false}]
 ["/1417615919-forth-migration.clj"  {:applied false}]]
```

I eventually need to manipulate it and return a new version of it. To find the value I need to manipulate I use `filter` and `first` which gives me the vector I'm after, E.G:

```
 ["/1417612450-second-migration.clj" {:applied false}]
```

My question is; how do I update the map for that particular item without having to `map` over the whole lot again? Can I use the above as a reference somehow?

Comment: Do you need `:applied`? Is the presence of a `:date-applied` not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the matching vector returned for other purposes, i.e. you're only finding it in order to update it, then use a map, instead of filter and first, with a function that checks each entry to see whether needs updating and returns either the changed/unchanged entry as appropriate.

```
(def test
  [["/1417612109-first-migration.clj"  {:applied true :date-applied 1423233980}]
   ["/1417612450-second-migration.clj" {:applied false}]
   ["/1417615919-forth-migration.clj"  {:applied false}]])

(map #(if (:applied (second %))
        % ; if applied is already true then use it unchanged
        (assoc-in % [1 :applied] true)) ; if applied is false update it
     test)

; (["/1417612109-first-migration.clj" {:applied true, :date-applied 1423233980}]
;  ["/1417612450-second-migration.clj" {:applied true}]
;  ["/1417615919-forth-migration.clj" {:applied true}])
```

If you don't need the outer collection to be a vector then you could make it a map and then use e.g. "/1417612450-second-migration.clj" as a key to assoc-in or update-in.

```
(def test-map
  {"/1417612109-first-migration.clj"  {:applied true :date-applied 1423233980}
   "/1417612450-second-migration.clj" {:applied false}
   "/1417615919-forth-migration.clj"  {:applied false}})

(def result ["/1417612450-second-migration.clj" {:applied false}])

(assoc-in test-map [(first result) :applied] true)

;{"/1417612109-first-migration.clj" {:applied true, :date-applied 1423233980},
; "/1417612450-second-migration.clj" {:applied true}, 
;"/1417615919-forth-migration.clj" {:applied false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update-in function https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in

```
(update-in my-vector [0 1 :applied] f)
```

where f is a function that takes the old value and return the new one. This example will update the applied value in the map from your first vector. It also works for deep structures. For more see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think the trouble is that I don't know what the index of the item I've found is. I've effectively used `(first (filter ...))` to get the structure I need from the larger structure.